# dynamic step in web_step.rb for updating a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

i want a step to update a table with the value supplied by the user in one of the cucumber scenarios .the step is :

```
Given /^I Update the (.+) field of the (.+) table by setting it as (.+)$/ do |col_name, table_name, value|

end
```

i want something like

```
table_name.update_column('#{col_name}',value)
```

or something that it works on all tables.

Comment: Shouldn't you save it and then get it from the database on show on the page? maybe i misunderstood you

Comment: its like having a step in your scenario that updates the table so that the next step can use that updation...hope i made it more clear

Comment: html tables are normally output-only and cannot be updated by the user.